# Colorbox iframe redirecting to page

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I am not sure if this is me or what but when I try and open an iframe with colorbox it starts to open but then refreshes the window to load that page in it.  I am not getting any errors and wonder if this has something to do with the page I am trying to load in the iframe.  I noticed that the [colorbox example iframe](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example3/) now shows threadless.com which I also got to work on my site.  If I try and replace the url in that demo with google.com then it does the same redirect.  I remember the demo used to have google as their example so I am assuming something has changed that is forcing this redirect.  Does anyone know anything about this or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sites simply can not be iframed.  It sounds like the site you are trying to iframe is detecting that it is being displayed in an iframe, then redirecting the parent window to their URL.  There are some 'frame-busting-busting' techniques, but I would recommend staying away from them.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jack. I have not encountered that before.  I remember your demo used to load google.  I ended up grabbing the data I needed using cross domain requests- http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ and loading it inline.